# In XSLT, how to give multiple or conditions in starts-with function?

Tags: xslt

Please suggest.

How place multiple 'or' conditions in Starts-with Function.

Starts-with.xml

```
<root>
 <Author><fnm>Kishan</fnm><snm>Thondaman</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Arun</fnm><snm>Mechiri</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Raju</fnm><snm>Bhaskar</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Mahesh</fnm><snm>Kumar</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Deepa</fnm><snm>Pandith</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Divya</fnm><snm>Pandith</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Vinay</fnm><snm>Mechiri</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Dishanth</fnm><snm>Bhaskar</snm></Author>
 <Author><fnm>Gagan</fnm><snm>Thondaman</snm></Author>
</root>
```

Starts-with.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Author">
        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(snm, 'Thondaman')">
                        <b><xsl:copy-of select="."/></b>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(snm, 'Mechiri')">
                        <b><xsl:copy-of select="."/></b>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(snm, 'Pandith')">
                        <i><xsl:copy-of select="."/></i>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(snm, 'Bhaskar')">
                        <i><xsl:copy-of select="."/></i>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Required XSLT tags: Two or more 'OR' conditions within one Starts-with, instead of individual find.

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(snm, '(Thondaman|Mechiri)')">
    <b><xsl:copy-of select="."/></b>
 </xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

naturally:

```
starts-with(snm, 'Mechiri') or starts-with(snm, 'Thondaman')
```

With XSLT 2.0 you can also use regular expressions (via [`fn:matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches)), but `starts-with()` itself only supports fixed strings.

Comment: Thank U, I hope "matches" only allowed the following format, "matches(.,'^(Thondamaan|Mechiri|Bhaskar)$')">. Like this format, '^(tttt|rrrr)$', is there. Thanks for suggestion.